# .Webs and anonymous access?

Tags: web-part, user-controls, access-denied

We're developing a public facing SharePoint site so it have anonymous access. To be able to run custom web parts that access lists/libraries we need to run with elevated privileges which works fine, no problem.

However, we have custom user control that displays the current sites sub sites and in the code we use .Webs which seems to be a problem (we get prompted for credentials on the page and when we debug).

```
private void LoadSubsites()
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl))
        {
            var sites = web.Webs.Select(w => new { Title = w.Title, Url = w.Url });
            if (sites != null)
            {
                rptSubsites.DataSource = sites;
                rptSubsites.DataBind();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do to enable anonymous users to access pages with this user control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) { using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID)) { ... } }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could open the site with the SystemAccount token. It is more recommended than using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.
I would do it like this:

```
private void LoadSubsites()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount)
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      var sites = web.Webs.Select(w => new { Title = w.Title, Url = w.Url });
      if (sites != null)
      {
        rptSubsites.DataSource = sites;
        rptSubsites.DataBind();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is preferred over the RWEP, we don't have to impersonate the user just open the SPSite as another user...

Comment: Also, check this blog post for more information: http://www.matchpointcommunity.com/blog/Posts/37/how-to-open-a-spsite-with-the-system-account-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 2):

First at all you should open new site context

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {

        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
        {
            var sites = web.Webs.Select(w => new { Title = w.Title, Url = w.Url });
            if (sites != null)
            {
                rptSubsites.DataSource = sites;
                rptSubsites.DataBind();
            }
          }}
    });
```

The second issue in your code is: you have memory leaks. `var sites = web.Webs.Select(w => new { Title = w.Title, Url = w.Url })`. To resolve it you can use `web.Webs.WebsInfo.Select(w => new { Title = w.Title, Url = w.ServerRelativeUrl })`

Comment: I updated my answer to show you memory leaks.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a go, any link where I can read about this memory leak?

Comment: The memory leak Alexander mentioned is pointed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx#sharepointobjmodel__spwebobjects. You are iterating over the webs of SPWeb.Webs, which each of it has to be disposed after accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use current context inside Elevated Privileges.

SPContext.Current object is created with security context of current logged in user. So you will get access denied error.

Use the following code -

```
 SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;  
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;  

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {  
  using (SPSite secureSite = new SPSite(site.ID)) {  
    using (SPWeb secureWeb= secureSite.OpenWeb(web.ID)) {  
     ListUSers(secureWeb);  
    }  
  }  
});
```

Code referred from this [msdn post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7af44d8c-c79b-45b2-8cd4-1663926abfdb)